# Using SyncFusion Blazor Charts in Linqpad

Tags: syncfusion, linqpad

Is there any way to use SyncFusion Blazor Charts in Linqpad?  I use Linqpad to make quick demos/PoCs and then once proven move them to Blazor.  Wanting to do this with charts.

Answer (score 0):

LINQPad primarily focuses on supporting C# code snippets, LINQ queries, and interacting with various data sources. While it provides a rich set of features for C# development and experimentation, it does not have built-in support for Blazor components. Unfortunately, in the standard version of LINQPad, it won't be able to directly use Blazor components or execute Blazor applications because LINQPad is not designed to be a full-fledged Blazor development environment.

If it is necessary to specifically work with Blazor charts, it's recommended to use Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code with the .NET SDK installed, as these tools are purpose-built for Blazor and .NET development and provide comprehensive support for creating and running Blazor applications and chart components.